# How can I find int element in List array

Tags: java, list

```
    List<double[]> x = new ArrayList<double[]>();
    x.add(new double[] { 1, 1.2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12  });
```

How can I use java code find not integer type(1.2) in x List?

Comment: `1.2` is not an integer.

Comment: What's wrong with a `for-loop`?

Comment: Are you hoping to find 1.2 taking advantage of the fact that it's sorted, or do you not have a guarantee that it's sorted?

Comment: I know use for loop. But I don't kwnow what's wrong below:
for( int i=0; i< x.get(0).length; i++)
{
   Log.e("log", (x.get(0)[i] instanceOf int) );
}

thank you ~

Comment: This may seem like grammar nit picking, but `x` is a `List<double[]>` so you won't be able to find anything in it but `double[]` objects. Do you actually mean find a value (likely `double` not `int`) in one of the `double[]` objects in `x`?

Comment: sorry. My express is not good. I meaning  how to use find 1.2 element in x list. If I get some double[] array. how to find 1.2 element have a decimal point element.  thank you response my question.

Comment: @dickfala i think i understood what u say, i answer u

Comment: oh man. someone who understood the question can also update the question so we can also understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
for (double d : x.get(0)) {
System.out.println("Not Integer:" + ((int) (d * 10) / 10 != d));
}
```

**Update** (this should be enough as well):

```
System.out.println("Not Integer:" + ((int) d != d));
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIt:** I just understood the question. So here is the updated answer

```
    List<double[]> x = new ArrayList<double[]>();
    x.add(new double[] { 1, 1.2, 2.9, 3.9, 4.1, 5.5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12  });

    List<Double> foundDoubles = new ArrayList<Double>();

    int i = 0;
    for(double d : x.get(0)) {
        i = (int)d;
        if(i != d) {
            foundDoubles.add(d);
        }
    }

    for(double d : foundDoubles) {
        System.out.println(d);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you compare a `double` with another `double` using `==` you will have a bad time...

Comment: If I don't know 1.2 element in this List. how to find 1.2 element? thanks.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza , can you please explain

Comment: Ok, I am lost with the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
for(double i : x) {
   String total2 = String.valueOf(i);
   if(i.contains(".")){
     // ...
   }
}
```

or you can use `if(Math.floor(i) > 0)` alter for `String` aproarch.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to Java :P But I think direct comparison wouldn't be good?

```
double a = 1;
double b = 1;
double c = a-b;
if (Math.abs(c) == 0) {...}
```

Basically set another primitive to the value your looking for. Subtract that value from the list. If one of the index's contains 1.2 than 1.2-1.2 = 0? Than you know where it is?

Comment: How is this different? You will still incur the same inaccuracies